# NLopt invalid argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, mathematical-optimization, nlopt

I use the NLopt library, with python bindings.

```
opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt_algorithm, N)
opt.set_max_objective(func_to_maximize)
opt.set_lower_bounds(lower_bounds)
opt.set_upper_bounds(upper_bounds)
opt.set_maxeval(100)
xopt = opt.optimize(x0)
```

when I use `nlopt_algorithm = nlopt.LN_SBPLX` it works well. However if I use `nlopt_algorithm = nlopt.GN_DIRECT_L`, it fails with the error:

> ValueError: nlopt invalid argument

Does anyone know why that is? Am I missing some arguments?

Comment: Have you tried any other global optimization algorithm ? GN_DIRECT_L works fine for me in C, nevertheless if I remember correctly, I had a similar error when choosing its unscaled variant.

Comment: Other global optimization fail. Let me check, it might be a problem with setting the bound constraints.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. It's because my constraints were not defined for all parameters.

Comment: I get same error even with using local optimizers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that not all my variables had bound constraints defined. For global optimization, NLopt requires all parameters to have an upper bound and a lower bound.